# How to not show a URL redirect to the user

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have an application where all the traffic to the URL path `/playback` must be processed by the PHP script `authCheck.php`.

This is OK, but I need to preserve the original URL in the browser for CSS URL tags:

```
RewriteRule ^/playback/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/authCheck.php?file=proxy/playback/$1  [NC]

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            #Require ip 127.0.0.1
    </Proxy>

    Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"

    ProxyPass               /proxy/playback         https://clientdomain/playback
    ProxyPassReverse        /proxy/playback         https://clientdomain/playback
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/playback/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/authCheck.php?file=proxy/playback/$1  [NC]
> ```

Remove the scheme + hostname from the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. If you include an absolute URL in the substitution then mod_rewrite implicitly triggers an external redirect (ie. the URL in the address bar changes). What you need is an *internal rewrite*.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/(playback/.*)$ /authCheck.php?file=proxy/$1  [NC]
```

I've included `playback/` in the captured *pattern*, so it saves you repeating this in the *substitution*.

NB: Only make it case-insensitive (`NC` flag) if you really need it.